# MySQL Keyword not supported: 'port' error in C# application

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to connect to MySQL database in my c# .Net application

I am getting this error when I try to connect: Keyword not supported: 'port'.

The  error appears to indicate an issue with my connection string

```
<add name="mydataEntities" connectionString="server=myserver.com;port=3306;password=xxxx;user id=yyyy;database= mydatabase;persistsecurityinfo=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

I have reference added for:
MySql.Data 6.9.7.0 (ADO.Net driver for MySQL)
And MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 6.9.7.0(Entity Framework 6.0 supported)

In my config I have:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
            <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
      </provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.7.0" newVersion="6.9.7.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

connection string is set here:

```
public class Repository
    {
        protected mydataEntities DbContext;

        public Repository()
        {

            DbContext = new mydataEntities (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydataEntities"].ConnectionString);
        }
}
```

I notice the stack trace appears to be using the System.Data.SqlClient provider as shown below:

I have removed the MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 references, Clean solution , add back references then rebuild …..

Can anyone help me to figure out the source of this error?

Why isn’t the MySQL connector using providerName: MySql.Data.MySqlClient as specified in my config.

```
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: *Can anyone help me to figure out the source of this error?* Where do you specify `mydataEntities` as the connection string to be used in your C# code?

Comment: I updated the ticket to show where I specify the connection string to use

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm running across a similar issue with the `port` keyword. I also run across the same issue with `allowuservariables` keyword. You shouldn't need to use the `port` keyword though because the default port is 3306 and it looks like that's what you're trying to connect to.

Comment: Strangely I have another application which uses the keyword port and it works

Comment: `new mydataEntities (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydataEntities "].ConnectionString);` Why is there a space in that connection string name? Does your `mydataEntities` constructor correctly call `base` with the name or connection string? Note that the `DbContext(String)` constructor takes a *name or connection string* so you should be able to just do `public mydataEntities(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)` and then `new mydataEntities("mydataEntities")`. But at this point...

Comment: ...I think the code would be redundant, because EF would just load `mydataEntities` connection string from the configuration by name by default. So something's up here.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I could remove that code with the connection string. The space is as a result of editing my real connection name .. There is no space.. I'l edit the question

Comment: I removed "Port" from the connection string. Now this error:A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server): Cant figure out why my application is still using: .Net SqlClient Data Provider-I removed all reference

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

I removed the following code from a partial class that overrides the connection string n the base.

```
public partial class mydataEntities
    {
        public mydataEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }
    }
```

I am still confused by the solution but it appears that with this code the connection was attempting to use the Mssql data provider instead of MySql