# Keyword not supported: 'port' - NpgSql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-web-app-service, npgsql

I have the following problem with the azure web app:

When publishing, the following error occurs:

```
Keyword not supported: 'port'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String keyword)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ConnectionStringMatcher.RemoveExtraSlashFromDataSourceName(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ConnectionStringMatcher.GetStandardConnectionString(String userConnectionString, Boolean isSqlCE)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlInfo.GetBuilder(String connectionString, String errorMessageFormat)
```

appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=xxxxx;Database=xxxxx;Port=5432;User Id=test;Password=xxxxx;Ssl Mode=Require;",
    "ProviderName": "Npgsql"
  },
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: Hi @Blasther12,can you successfully perform the migration?

Comment: Good night, my PostgreSql was created in azure, I use the same connection string, in local test the migration occurs normally. But every publication has this error.

Comment: @Blasther12 My suggestion is to delete `Port=5432`.

Comment: @Blasther12 No document tells you that when .Net connects to `NpgSql`, the string requires the Port parameter. Please delete and try again.

Comment: @Blasther12 Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: I performed the test and the following error occurs: "The database could not be created"

Comment: Repeating an 'Add' operation on any dbFullSql object (database = xxxx; data source = xxxx; user id = xxx). Attempt 9 out of 10.
C: \ Program Files \ dotnet \ sdk \ 5.0.100 \ Sdks \ Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish \ targets \ PublishTargets \ Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets (140,5): Warning: Not possible to create the database 'xxxxx'.

Comment: C: \ Program Files \ dotnet \ sdk \ 5.0.100 \ Sdks \ Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish \ targets \ PublishTargets \ Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets (140,5): Warning: Not possible connect to database 'xxxx'.
Repeating the 'Add' operation on the dbFullSql object (server = xxxx; database = xxx; user id = xxxxx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your PostgreSQL server created in Azure?

**According to the error message, the port parameter should not appear in the connection string.**

[image]

If it is created in azure, your DefaultConnection should be like the following string.

```
Server=jasonp2testsql.postgres.database.azure.com;Database={your_database};Port=5432;User Id=jasonp2@jasonp2testsql;Password={your_password};Ssl Mode=Require;
```

You also can refer to this post.

[C# SqlConnection Exception: Keyword not Supported 'Port'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576264/c-sharp-sqlconnection-exception-keyword-not-supported-port)

And [the offical document](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html) is useful to you.